# How can i add venmo payment method in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, payment-gateway, venmo

I've connected the firebase and want to send payment through phone number. When I click the button the payment goes to the venmo. How can i do that is there any way?

I've tried using flutter_braintree package but I really can't get to solve the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The qualifications for processing Venmo in your own mobile app have a pretty narrow application. See https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/articles/guides/payment-methods/venmo#availability for details.  But if you fit within the rules, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_braintree probably will be your next step.